# uploads images to file path but error when saving to database

Tags: python, html, sqlite, sqlalchemy

Code does upload image to path, but I receive the the following error when form is submitted:

> sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding
> parameter 5 - probably unsupported type.

Other code I have tried will allow submission but wont upload to path. I am very new at programming and am struggling a bit to complete this portion of my code.

```
@views.route('/createNew', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def createNew():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        recipeName = request.form.get('recipeName')
        meat = request.form.get('meat')
        totalTime = request.form.get('totalTime')
        preparation = request.form.get('preparation')
        instructions = request.form.get('instructions')

        img = request.files['img']
        imgName = str(uuid.uuid1()) + os.path.splitext(img.filename)[1]
        img.save(os.path.join('package/static/userImages', imgName))

        if len(recipeName) < 1:
            flash('Recipe is too short!', category='error')
        else:
            new_recipe = Recipe(recipeName=recipeName, meat=meat, totalTime=totalTime,
                                preparation=preparation, instructions=instructions, img=img, imgName=imgName,  user_id=current_user.id)
            db.session.add(new_recipe)
            db.session.commit()

            flash('Recipe added!', category='success')

    return render_template("createNew.html", user=current_user)



{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Create New
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1 class="createNew-header" align="center">New Recipe</h1>
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush" id="recipes">
  
</ul>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label class="createNew-label"> Recipe Name:</label>
    <textarea name="recipeName" id="recipeName" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipe Name"></textarea>

  <label class="createNew-label">Type of Meat(s):</label>
    <textarea name="meat" id="typeOfMeat" class="form-control" placeholder="Type of Meat(s) Used"></textarea>

  <label class="createNew-label">Total Time:</label>
    <textarea name="totalTime" id="totalTime" class="form-control" placeholder="Total Time"></textarea>

  <label class="createNew-label">Preparation:</label>
    <textarea name="preparation" id="preparation" class="form-control" placeholder="Preparation"></textarea>

  <label class="createNew-label">Instructions:</label>
    <textarea name="instructions" id="instructions" class="form-control" placeholder="Instructions"></textarea>
  <br />


  <label class="uploadImage-label">Upload Image: </label>
    <br />
  <input type="file" name="img" id="img" accept="image/*" capture>
 
  <br />
  <div align="center">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add Recipe</button>
  </div>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: The error probably comes from mismatching between types of incomming request and `Recipe` table. Coud you show examplary `request.form` data and `Recipe` sqlalchemy model?

Comment: Figured out my issue thank you for the help much appreciated.